# viewing documentation of tex packages

Tags: documentation

I'm new to Latex and I was wondering if it is possible to look up the documentation of tex packages in the terminal like with man pages? I find myself frequently having to look up stuff online that I think is very basic, like for the `titlepage` environment. I would ideally love to have a "man" page for this open while working on the document.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The bash command `texdoc` opens the package documentation. That is usually a pdf file.

Comment: Although `texdoc titlepage` brings up the German documentation for the `fhACtitlepage` package.  For an environment, you'd want to look up the package that provides that environment.

Comment: `man texdoc && man texdoctk`

Comment: thanks ! I wasn't aware of this. What about environments that don't require packages to be included like `itemize`, `table`, etc .. ? What should I for search using `texdoc` then ?

Comment: For documentation of the core LaTeX functionality, you can use `texdoc latex2e`.

Comment: And `texdoctk` → `Guides and tutorials`

Answer (score 1):

The `texdoc` command brings up the (usually PDF) documentation. At least of Fedora Linux you have to instal the `-doc` packages separately (they usually aren't installed as they take up a lot of space).

You could also just search the 'net, or look it up in [CTAN](https://ctan.org).

Note that for some packages the "official" documentation isn't in English, altough most of the time there are translations available.